# Try catch exception (letter in int)

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to use a try catch structure to show an error when I try to input a letter into a string. Which exception should I be using for this? the console shows me InputMismatchException but this does not work.

input that works:

`beginnen = 1`

input that doesn't work:

`beginnen = a`

it obviously doesn't work cause i'm putting a string into an int, I just want to have a message show up when this occurs

```
int beginnen;
String error = "Something went wrong";
try {
   beginnen = Input.readInt();
}
   catch (InputMismatchException IME) {
        System.out.println(error);
   }
```

error that shows up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? show us `Input.readInt();`

Comment: What do you mean by `does not work`? What input did you gave? And what output did you got back? And please post some more code.

Comment: Also, IME and error ? error not defined?

Comment: use NumberFormatException

Comment: @Aniket, does javadoc say that? I couldn't find it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readInt()

Comment: Updated the original post, sorry for being a bit unclear

Comment: What do mean by "message show up"? The Exception is your message!? Try what Richard answered.

Comment: I'm sorry, English is not my mother tongue. I just want the string error to be displayed when anything that does not fit an integer is entered in the input.readInt()

Comment: Ah, now it's clear what "error" is ... So what you are trying to say is that the Exception is in fact thrown but the "error" is not written to System.out ?

Comment: That's right, however someone posted an answer telling me to use 'Throwable' instead and this did the trick. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jente `catch(Throwable t)` is not so good (it's okay to use it temporarily for diagnostic purposes as suggested in the answer). You wouldn't want to swallow and ignore an `OutOfMemoryError` and several others. Even `catch(Exception e)` is almost always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @DanielFischer what should I use then?

Comment: @Jente To diagnose the exact class, catching `Throwable` is okay (though `Exception` would be less of a sledge hammer and almost certainly be enough). Find out the exact exception class being thrown as suggested, and then catch that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the documentation is foggy, use experiment:

```
 try {
   beginnen = Input.readInt();
 } catch (Throwable x) {
     System.err.println("Catched "+x.getClass().getName());
 }
```

This will print the exact class name for you and you can later change your code to catch the exception of this class. This will also show for you, maybe just nothing is actually thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Your **Try/Catch** expression looks fine to me, however you've mistakenly referenced **error**, which is not defined anywhere.

Try changing it to `System.out.println(IME.getMessage());`

Comment: Error is a string with an error message in there, sorry for being unclear.